# Reverse the direction of the color in linear gradient legend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, legend, linear-gradients

I have an continuous legend(both vertical and horizontal) and currently the color are flown from red to blue but I want it to be in reverse direction like from blue to red. I have shared by code snippet and also the Fiddle link

Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/64drqnxf/

```
// create the legend

const id = "linear-gradient-" + id + "0";
linearGradient = defs
.append("linearGradient")
.attr("id", id)
.attr("x1", "0%")
.attr("x2", horizontal ? "100%" : "0%")
.attr("y1", "0%")
.attr("y2", horizontal ? "0%" : "100%");

// append the color
linearGradient
.selectAll("stop")
.data(itemColor)
.enter()
.append("stop")
.attr("offset", function (data) {
return data.offset + "%";
})
.attr("stop-color", function (data) {
return data.color;
});

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svgLegend
.append("rect")
.attr("x", 35)
.attr("y", horizontal ? 70 : 18)
.attr("width", horizontal ? "189" : 20)
.attr("height", horizontal ? 20 : "149")
.style("fill", "url(#" + currentIndex + ")");

// create tick
const xLeg = scaleLinear().domain([min, max]).range([10, 158]);
let yLeg = scaleLinear().domain([max, min]).range([10, 158]);

const horizontalAxisLeg = axisBottom(xLeg).tickValues(colorScale.domain());
const VerticalAxisLeg = axisRight(yLeg).tickSize(20).tickValues(colorScale.domain());

Also my data is structed something like this

const data = [
[0.0, 255, 0, 0],
[0.25, 255, 255, 0],
[0.5, 0, 255, 0],
[0.75, 0, 255, 255],
[1.0, 0, 0, 255]
]

Where first value in the array is point and next three values are rgb values.
0(point) --> color(255, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change linerGradient to start from right. Right now you are filling from Left. **You can do this by changing x1 and x2 in your gradient def.**

```
linearGradient = defs
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", id)
  .attr("x1", "100%")  //Change this to 100%
  .attr("x2", horizontal ? "100%" : "0%") //This to 0%
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("y2", horizontal ? "0%" : "100%");
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg class="axis" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); border-radius: 5px;">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="100%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000"></stop>
            <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#ffff00"></stop><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#00ff00"></stop>
            <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#00ffff"></stop><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000ff"></stop>
        </linearGradient></defs>
        <text class="legendTitle" x="25" y="20">Legend</text>
        <rect x="25" y="30" width="250" height="25" style="fill: url(&quot;#linear-gradient&quot;);"></rect>
          <g transform="translate(15, 55)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 700;">
          <path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M10,6V0H258V6"></path>
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(10,0)">
            <line stroke="currentColor" y2="6"></line><text fill="currentColor" y="9" dy="0.71em">0.00</text><g>
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(258,0)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="6"></line><text fill="currentColor" y="9" dy="0.71em">0.35</text></g></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: But when I try to change in my code, the whole legend takes only one color. Actually I am appending the offset like this const offset = point * 100.0; , where point is the value for ex: 0 point show red, for 1 show blue etc.

Comment: You dont have to change the offset or data, only change direction of the linear gradient. Dont reverse the data. Just change x1 and x2 for direction of the linear gradient. I only changed x1 and x2 in <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="100%" x2="0%" y1="0%" y2="0%">

Comment: I changed for horizontal legend, it gives only one color. How about vertical legend ? Do I need to try y1 and y2 ?

Comment: .attr("x1", horizontal ? "100%" : "0%")
  .attr("x2", "0%")

Comment: Thanks it work for vertical case (goes from blue to red (up to down)) but for horizontal I want it to be reverse(from red to blue(left to right)) but horizontal also it takes from blue to red.

Comment: I wrote 2 separate gradient, one for horizontal and one for vertical by adding condition and it seems to work as what I expected.

Comment: Yes you can create any direction based on x1,x2,y1 and y2. Even you can create diagonal gradients.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246045/discussion-between-b-kalra-and-coder91).

Comment: Can we use Linear gradient for logarithm interpolation/sampling ?

Answer (score 0):

I think reversing your `<stop>` element should do:

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg class="axis" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); border-radius: 5px;">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0000ff"></stop>  
            <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#00ffff"></stop>

<stop offset="50%" stop-color="#00ff00"></stop>
          <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#ffff00"></stop>
         
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000"></stop>
        </linearGradient></defs>
        <text class="legendTitle" x="25" y="20">Legend</text>
        <rect x="25" y="30" width="250" height="25" style="fill: url(&quot;#linear-gradient&quot;);"></rect>
          <g transform="translate(15, 55)" fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: 700;">
          <path class="domain" stroke="currentColor" d="M10,6V0H258V6"></path>
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(10,0)">
            <line stroke="currentColor" y2="6"></line><text fill="currentColor" y="9" dy="0.71em">0.00</text><g>
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(258,0)"><line stroke="currentColor" y2="6"></line><text fill="currentColor" y="9" dy="0.71em">0.35</text></g></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I have an data something like this 0: {offset: 0, color: '#ff0000'} 1: {offset: 100, color: '#0000ff'} . I could use reverse function to reverse the order but how to reverse only color without reversing the offset.